# Memory leak in CSV to array function

Tags: php, arrays, csv

As a part of an import class we use this csvToArray function. It worked fine in the past but now it 'broke' somehow.

We get an "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 78 bytes)" error.

```
private function _csvToArray($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;
    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row); // THIS IS THE LINE WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This could mean the file got to big, but it only has 5 lines extra since we started to use this script...

Comment: The function has nothing to do with it. Search the `php.ini` file for `memory_limit` and set it to whatever number you feel comfortable with. In mb. Or -1 for "unlimited".

Comment: @Andrew That just shifts the problem, though

Comment: @Damien Pirsy Yep, it does, no argument there. Besides the obvious alternative of writing cleaner, I guess is the word here, code, what alternatives does he have?

Comment: @Andrew I would love to keep our server admin as a friend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would take less memory if the `$header` row was stored once and used as an index.  As it is, each non-header row of the table will have a copy of the header strings in it as the keys.  You could cut the memory use in half (almost) by changing the `while` loop to this:

```
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if(!$header) {
            $header = $row;
            $flipheader = array_flip($header);
        }
        else
            $data[] = $row;  // Just the data
    }
```

Then reference the flipped header index to lookup the values, like this:

```
$index = $flipheader['columnName'];  // if you need to lookup rows by column name
$value = $data[0][$index];
```

If you only need the header strings when formatting output, and not for looking up values, it's even simpler because you can use a numeric index to get at the values, and use the same index to access the `$header` string when needed. In this case you wouldn't need the `$flipheader` variable.

Comment: I should be able to look things up by column name at all times. So the function should return both the `$flipHeader` and the `$data` array. This way I could do $data[0][$flipHeader['columnName']] right?
I'll give this one a shot :)

Comment: No luck, error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes). This time at the `fgetcsv` function line.

Comment: Ain't it strange the memory size is 134217728 and it fails when handling 72 bytes ?

Comment: If each row is about 70-80 bytes you'd have to have a HUGE file to chew up that much memory. I suspect somehow your while loop isn't ending. Try a really small csv file as a test. If that fails then try printing each row to see if it's getting into an infinite loop.

Comment: The CSV I tested with has 43935 rows. I nicely asked the server admin to boost the memory size to 250 and now the cron does not complain about any other errors.

Comment: I'll accept the answer allready because I did use the `array_flip()` you suggested and it seems to help a bit.